# React Select removes German Characters (and other non English Characters)

Tags: reactjs, select, internationalization

Having an issue where React Select removes accents and modifiers from German characters such as the `U` in München or the `ß`, and transforms it to `s`.

Input:

`München`

Outputs:

`muchen`

expected: 

`München`

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out...

React Select has some undocumented props you can pass in `ignoreAccents` and `ignoreCase`. These two props are default to `true` and will modify the input into the Select. Simply pass `ignoreAccents={false}` and you will get your ü in `münchen.